# Custom Bootloader for Kinetis MKE06Z microcontrollers on IAR EWARM issue

Tags: c, arm, microcontroller, bootloader, iar

First I'd like to introduce myself, as I'm new to the site. I'm an Electronic Engineer, specialized in embedded systems design and development. I've been gathering info from the site for a long time, and I think that there's a lot of people with great deal of knowledge. I'm hoping some other of you may have stumbled upon this or a similar issue.

I've been having some trouble in the implementation of a custom bootloader for a Kinetis MKE06Z microcontroller, not in the bootloader itself but in the relocation of the application code and the behavior after jumping to it. The application is completely coded in C.

The bootloader executes everything as expected, determines if it should run or jump to user application. This is the sequence that implements the jump:

```
__disable_interrupt();
SCB->VTOR = RELOCATION_VECTOR_ADDR & 0x3FFFFE00;
JumpToUserApplication(RELOCATION_VECTOR_ADDR);
```

where:

```
void JumpToUserApplication(uint32_t userStartup)
{
    /* set up stack pointer */
    asm("LDR    r1, [r0]");
    asm("MOV    r13, r1");
    /* jump to application reset vector */
    asm("ADDS   r0,r0,#0x04 ");
    asm("LDR    r0, [r0]");
    asm("BX     r0");
}
```

as implemented in **Frescale's AN4767**.

So far, so good. Once the jump is executed, I trace the application behavior (on the Disassembly Window) and find out after some instructions, it gets stuck at some specific address with a jump instruction, which ends up being an infinite loop. I then run it step by step to determine which was the instruction that causes this malfunction. It's very strange, as it is running OK and suddenly jumps to a RAM address. A couple of cycles and then jumps to the infinite loop. I took note of the addresses with the instruction causing this strange jump and the one with the infinite loop. I look at the core registers and find out there is an exception, and notice it's the number `0x03` (**Hard Fault**). Then switch to debugging the user application.

Once in the user application, I start debugging. The user application works fine running like this (no jump from the bootloader). Then I look for the relevant addresses and discover that the routine causing the hard fault when jumping from bootloader is from IAR: `__iar_data_init3`. The thing is, it's part of a precompiled library and I'm not sure if it's safe to remove it (by removing the `__iar_program_start` and replacing it directly with the call to `main` on the startup file.

The real question is: why does the application behave like that after the jump from the booloader but not if there is no such jump? Why does this routine jumps to a RAM address (when it shouldn't)?

Of course, it may be a little to specific, but hopefully there's someone that can help me.

Comment: Can you keep the post limited to your question, and elaborate it if possible? It is very generic, try being more specific by providing code snippets of parts you don't understand...

Comment: post a simple example of what you have done and what you think it should be doing.

Comment: Sorry I hit Enter key and posted an incomplete question. I'm not sure, tho, this is specific enough.

Comment: `__iar_program_start` is run before calling `main`, because it initializes the variables with static storage duration (`.bss` and `.data` sections). It's not safe to remove unless you want all variables to be uninitialized.

Comment: Did you disable interrupts, and set correct VTOR and stack pointer when setting the program pointer from bootloader to application start?

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot that in the description of the problem. Yes, I did so:

`__disable_interrupt();`
`SCB->VTOR = RELOCATION_VECTOR_ADDR;`
`JumpToUserApplication(RELOCATION_VECTOR_ADDR);`

It's loosely based on Freescale's AN4767.

Comment: Is the application actually linked to run from the address it's being relocated to?

Comment: @Notlikethat. Of course. Both linker configuration files have been edited, so in one case ROM is limited, and in the other, the vector table and the .text section are located where I want them to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that something IAR does with the linker configuration is not very clear to me, but has something to do with this problem. The thing is I relocated .text segment:

```
define symbol __ICFEDIT_intvec_start__ = 0x00001800;
define symbol __ICFEDIT_region_ROM_start__ = 0x00002000;
define symbol __ICFEDIT_region_ROM_end__  = 0x0000FFFF;

define region APP_ROM = mem:[from (__ICFEDIT_region_ROM_start__)  to (__ICFEDIT_region_ROM_end__)];

place at address mem:__ICFEDIT_intvec_start__ { readonly section .intvec };
place at start of APP_ROM { readonly section .text };
```

It seems that the linker doesn't appreciate this and something make the app misbehave when jumping from other app. Instead of this, keeping the original .icf file and editing within the GUI only the .intvec_start solved the problem, but code starts right next to the vector table. Not an issue, but I wanted to relocate code a little farther.

Thanks.